# Is there more simple way to change list elements

Tags: python, list, decode

I have some code:

```
report['ipconfig'] = [line.decode('cp866') for line in report['ipconfig']]
```

Can I make this code more simple?

Comment: This looks pretty darn fine and simple to me; what is the problem with it, exactly?

Comment: I'll thought there is another way to change elements "in-place", like in 2nd answer. But now I see that my code looks like better)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seomthing like this ?

```
for i, line in enumerate(report['ipconfig']):
    report['ipconfig'][i] = line.decode('cp866')
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is more simple (what does that even mean?), but it's a different way of doing it:

```
report['ipconfig'] = map(lambda x : x.decode('cp866'), report['ipconfig'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use codecs module to read initial data. Wrap your reader in codecs.getreader and reencoding becomes not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something more verbose?

```
lst = list()
for line in report['ipconfig']:
    lst.append(line.decode('cp866'))
report['ipconfig'] = lst
```

Comment: IMHO, too many line for nothing)

Comment: Yes, it was the point (since we didn't know what you meant by "more simple")